# Dirac delta function

Tags: calculus, functions, physics, distribution-theory

1)Prove that the dirac delta function property:
$$ x\delta'(x)=-\delta(x)$$

2)and :
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x)f(x)dx=-f'(0) \  $$

Comment: By symmetric, do you actually mean that $\delta(-x) = \delta(x)$?

Comment: I still remember we almost had a revolution in class when our professor introduced the derivative of the delta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to prove these properties: the naive way, and the rigorous way.  The naive way is simple: the derivative of a distribution is defined through integration by parts: 
$$
T^\prime[f]=\int T^\prime f=-\int T f^\prime
$$ So for the first one,

$$
\int \delta^\prime(x) (xf(x))dx=-\int\delta(x)(xf(x))^\prime dx=-\int\delta(x)(f(x)+xf^\prime(x))dx=-f(0)
$$ (you should justify that $xf(x)$ is still a suitable test function, and verify that the last integration is indeed $-f(0)$. )

For the second one,

$$
\int \delta^\prime(x)=-\int\delta(x)f^\prime(x)dx=-f^\prime(0)
$$

The rigorous method requires us to take a "delta-sequence" $\delta_n(x)$, then use "normal" integration by parts and take the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Would you please give more intuitive explanation about "the derivative of a distribution is defined through integration by parts:"? $T^\prime[f]=\int T^\prime f=-\int T f^\prime$ which looks very nice but too abstract to fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  both of these can be proved by integrating by parts.  Integrate the $\delta'(x)dx$ and differentiate the rest.